# Gulp/Grunt grab all color variables in a Stylus sheet, and write them to a file as variable definitions

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp

From a set of `.styl` files in a directory, find all CSS properties that use variables as colors, and generate a `colors.styl` file (bonus: or insert the resulting string within a placeholder in an existing file) that defines those variables.

### Example:

```
.
└── styl
    ├── library
    │   └── palettes-package.styl
    └── my-styles.styl

2 directories, 2 files
```

#### styl/my-styles.styl

```
@import "library/palettes-package"

body 
    background-color: palettes-red-1

p
    color: palettes-grey-1

span
    border: 1px solid #000000
```

#### styl/libraries/palettes-package.styl

```
palettes-red-1 = #FF0000
palettes-grey-1 = #EEEEEE
```

#### Result

```
palettes-red-1 = #FF0000
palettes-grey-1 = #EEEEEE
```

As a string to be appended into a file.

Bonus also if it includes

```
calculated-1 = #000000
```

and `#000000` is replaced for `calculated-1` in my-styles.styl.

Answer (score 1):

You could give https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-css-parse a try and post process the results using a regulär expression on the value property to identify rules containing color codes (hex rgb and rgba values).